# How can I populate an optional collection property with a default value?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a part of a json file that represents this class.

```
public class Command
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("Json!")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    //[DefaultValue(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

where two properties are optional: `Text` and `Parameters`. I'd like them to be populated with default values.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to make it work for both of them.

- If I use the `DefaultValueHandling.Populate` option then `Text` will be populated but `Parameters` remains `null`.
- If I use `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` then it'll be the other way around.
- If I set `[DefaultValue(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))]` on the `Parameters` property it'll crash.

**Quesiton**: Is there a way to make it work for all properties?

*I'd like to have it not-null so that I don't have to check it in other part of the code.*

---

Demo of what I have tried:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"
[
    {
        ""Name"": ""Hallo"",
        ""Text"": ""Json!""
    },
        {
        ""Name"": ""Hallo"",
    }
]
";

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Command[]>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate,
        ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse
    });

    result.Dump(); // LINQPad
}
```

Comment: What exception did you get when it crashed on the dictionary? I am wondering if it is because you'd need to instantiate something not just declare a type?

Comment: @BenHall it says: `Could not cast or convert from System.RuntimeType to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.String].` but I've just noticed that I was using the wrong overload, there is one like `Type, String` that made me stuck too as I don't believe a dictionary can be created from a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of specifying a global `DefaultValueHandling` via settings, use  `[JsonProperty]` attributes to set the `DefaultValueHandling` as you need it for each individual property:

```
public class Command
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("Json!")]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Then, deserialize like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Command[]>(json);
```

Comment: I tried other combinations and they work too. For example I can set `Populate` globally and `Ignore` on particular properties so that I don't have to decorate all of them but just the collections types.

Comment: Yes, that is a better solution if you have many properties and you want most of them to work one way but just a few to work the other way.